# Mock a function of an object in Jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I have a function of the method signature

```js
//1 const changeFuncInObj = (myObj, someBool) => {
//2    myObj.anObjFunction = (event) => {
//3        return externalFunction(event.data) && someBool
//4    }
//5 }
```

I want to test this function but I am unable to go inside line number 3 due to incorrect mocking

My test file is as follow:

```
test('test function inside object', () => {
          const myObj = {
            anObjFunction: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
                return {
                    externalFunction: jest
                        .fn()
                        .mockReturnValueOnce(true),
                }
            }),
        }
        let result = changeFuncInObj(myObj, true)
     
        expect(result).toEqual(undefined) // should be true or false based on `externalFunction` and `someBool`
})
```

Is there a way to mock the object for all possible inside function, boolean variable and internal function values?

Comment: Perhaps you should mock `externalFunction` instead?

Comment: As I said, I am not able to mock `anObjFunction` itself, so the test does not go till `externalFunction` anyway

Answer (score 0):

Inside `changeFuncInObj` you are reassigning the method `anObjFunction` of the `myObj` to some other function.

This is the test for the code you have:

```js
const myObj = {
  anObjFunction: undefined,
};

expect(myObj.anObjFunction).not.toBeDefined();
changeFuncInObj(myObj, true);
expect(myObj.anObjFunction).toBeDefined();
```

The function `changeFuncInObj` does not return anything so the result will always be `undefined`.

In case the `externalFunction` would look like this. The test could look like this:

```js
const externalFunction = (data) => data;

test("should work", () => {
  const myObj = {
    anObjFunction: undefined,
  };

  changeFuncInObj(myObj, true);

  expect(myObj.anObjFunction({ data: true })).toEqual(true);
  expect(myObj.anObjFunction({ data: false })).toEqual(false);

  changeFuncInObj(myObj, false);
  expect(myObj.anObjFunction({ data: true })).toEqual(false);
  expect(myObj.anObjFunction({ data: false })).toEqual(false);
});
```